# Button onclick event not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've checked around and read a couple articles on this issue and tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.  The issue is when the button is clicked the first time nothing happens.  The second time its clicked then the event and ajax request is fired off.  In addition to having to click the button twice the ajax data is requested and displayed twice.  Ive seen a few articles that said check the buttons visibility and if it is checking to turn off/on another elements visibility in this case its not.  Additionally  I have the onclick of the button calling a method to fire the ajax.  Whats strange is when i removed the code from the method and place it in the DOM ready the event fires the first time but my ajax data never returns

Button HTML :

```
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="GetInfo();" type="button" value="Find ID" class="button-ffe" />
```

Here is the click code :

```
    function GetInfo() {
    var term = $('#txtUtente').val();

    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {

        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerWidth;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/GetPTSID',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ term: term }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = 'none';

                $('#infoFoundID').html(data.d[0]);
                $('#foundInfoMessage, #userInformation').show();
                $('#registerProductInfo').hide();                    
                var partTable = $('#partTable tbody');

                $(data.d).each(function (index, id) {
                    partTable.append('<tr> <td>' + id + '</td><td>' + '<input onclick="GetPartNumber();" id="Button1" type="button" value="Copy Number" />' + '</td></tr>');
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
} //end getinfo
```

Comment: Well on the first click you are assigning another event to it by $('#btnSearch').click(function ().. that is why the first time nothing happens.

Comment: This is what happens when you mix event binding with inline invocation.  Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the event in the first click, so the code runs like you write.

You can remove the first function definition :

```
    var term = $('#txtUtente').val();

$('#btnSearch').click(function () {

    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerWidth;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/GetPTSID',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ term: term }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = 'none';

            $('#infoFoundID').html(data.d[0]);
            $('#foundInfoMessage, #userInformation').show();
            $('#registerProductInfo').hide();                    
            var partTable = $('#partTable tbody');

            $(data.d).each(function (index, id) {
                partTable.append('<tr> <td>' + id + '</td><td>' + '<input onclick="GetPartNumber();" id="Button1" type="button" value="Copy Number" />' + '</td></tr>');
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Would need to move the term variable into the click function.

Comment: and also remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML element.

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry for forget it :(

Answer (score 0):

So, the first click will run GetInfo() - which, adds a jQuery click listener (but doesn't run it)

then the second click runs the function defined in the click listener - and GetInfo - which adds ANOTHER instance of the jQuery stuff

then the third click runs the function defined in the click listener, twice - and GetInfo - which adds ANOTHER instance of the jQuery stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery click function is in your `GetInfo()` function. Change your JS to:

```
var getInfo = {
    init: function() {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            getInfo.click();
        });
    },
    click: function() {
        var term = $('#txtUtente').val();

        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {

            var winW = window.innerWidth;
            var winH = window.innerWidth;
            var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
            dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
            dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/GetPTSID',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ term: term }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = 'none';

                    $('#infoFoundID').html(data.d[0]);
                    $('#foundInfoMessage, #userInformation').show();
                    $('#registerProductInfo').hide();                    
                    var partTable = $('#partTable tbody');

                    $(data.d).each(function (index, id) {
                        partTable.append('<tr> <td>' + id + '</td><td>' + '<input onclick="GetPartNumber();" id="Button1" type="button" value="Copy Number" />' + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};

getInfo.init();
```

Now you can change your html to:

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Find ID" class="button-ffe" />
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

use focusableInTouchMode=false in xml it works for me